# expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before string constant

Tags: c++

I am only in the beginning steps of this program but I like to compile as I am making code. Also I am very new with ADTs so when making this code I ran into some problems that I have no idea what they mean.

Expression.h

```
#include "header.h" //Library that contains thing like iomanip, cstring, etc.

class Expression
{
        private:
          char *ieEXP; //Array of characters
          char *peEXP; //Array of characters
          const int MAX = 40; //Max size for the array
        public:
          //Initialize both arrays to 0
          Expression(){ieEXP[MAX] = {0}, peEXP[MAX] = {0}};

          Expression(const Expression &);

          //Destroy contents within the array after program completes
          ~Expression(){ieEXP[MAX] = {0}, peEXP[MAX] = {0}};


          //void ReadInFix(char *ieEXP);
          //void PrintInFix(char *ieEXP);
          //void StrCatch();
          //bool IsOperator();
          //void IntoPostFix(char *peEXP);
          //void PrintPostFix(char *peEXP);
          //int Priority();
};
```

Compilation

```
g++ -c Expression.h
```

This is the exact error that I get

```
Expression.h:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, 
or type conversion before string constant
```

Also other methods have not been used yet simply just creating the class right now, and int main has not called anything yet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is probably to not compile a header file, as g++ doesn't recognize *.h as a source file. You probably want to create a .cpp file that includes your header, and compile *that*. g++ will recognize the .cpp and treat it properly.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I used .cc instead, homework specification for class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Expression(){ieEXP[MAX] = {0}, peEXP[MAX] = {0}};
```

ieEXP and peEXP are pointers not arrays.

Comment: instead would i do char ieEXP[MAX] and peEXP[MAX]?